# Angular 4 : Build to prod: Property is private and only accessible within class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, production-environment

i'm using Angular 4 , i'm running : `ng build --prod`

i'm catching this :

```
ng build --prod
Your global Angular CLI version (1.2.2) is greater than your local
version (1.0.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
Hash: 7fce5d10c4c3ac9745e8
Time: 68351ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.7790a64cc25c48ae62ea.bundle.js (polyfills) 177 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.f10680210e9e45ed33cc.bundle.js (main) 382 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.d2e6408caea42ccabf99.bundle.css (styles) 175 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.fc69ec31f7ef40b5fffb.bundle.js (vendor) 5.9 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.91747411075ce6c7f438.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ng:///D:/Sources/DotNet/NextGCClientWeb/src/app/login/login.component.html (11,3): Property 'activatedRoute' is private and only accessible within class 'Login
Component'.

ERROR in ng:///D:/Sources/DotNet/NextGCClientWeb/src/app/login/login.component.html (11,3): Property 'activatedRoute' is private and only accessible within class 'Login
Component'.
```

this error seems to be strange :

```
ERROR in 
    ng:///D:/Sources/DotNet/NextGCClientWeb/src/app/login/login.component.html (11,3): Property 'activatedRoute' is private and only accessible within class 'Login Component
```

The indicated component in the error is the follwoing :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { SessionService } from './../../shared/service';

import { User } from './../../model';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  error: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  stayConnected: Boolean;

  constructor (
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    if (activatedRoute.snapshot.params['keyWording']) {
      this.sessionService.logInWithFinalization(activatedRoute.snapshot.params['keyWording']);
    }
  }

  logIn() {
    this.sessionService.logIn(this.email, this.password, this.stayConnected).subscribe(
      () => {
        if (this.sessionService.pageRequestedInUnauthenticated == null) {
          this.router.navigate(['/welcome']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate([this.sessionService.pageRequestedInUnauthenticated]);
        }
      },
      (error: Response) => this.error = error.json()
    );
  }
}
```

**The html view:**

```
<div id="divLogin">
  <h1>Se connecter</h1><br>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg" id="iconEmail"></i>
  <input type="text" id="email" [(ngModel)]="email" (keyup.enter)="logIn()" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email" autofocus />
  <i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" id="iconPassword"></i>
  <input type="password" id="password" [(ngModel)]="password" (keyup.enter)="logIn()" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" />
  <button (click)="logIn()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Connexion</button>
  <span id="containerStayConnected" title="Non implémenté"><input type="checkbox" id="stayConnected" [(ngModel)]="stayConnected" /><label for="stayConnected">Restez connecté</label></span>
  <a id="forgetPassword" title="Non implémenté">Mot de passe oublié</a><br><br><br>
  <a routerLink="/inscription">S'inscrire</a><br>
  {{ error }}
</div>

<div class="confirmationMessage" *ngIf="activatedRoute.snapshot.params['keyWording'] == 'validateInscription'"><br>Un lien de confirmation vous a été envoyé sur votre boîte email afin de valider votre compte. Merci.</div>

<div id="piedDePage"></div>
```

when running **ng serve** am not catching it .

**Any propositions ??**

Comment: @firaskoubaa, Change `private activatedRoute` to `public activatedRoute`.May be your problem will be solved.

Comment: The property `activatedRoute` is defined as `private` with `private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Changing to public activatedRoute**

You need to make your activatedRoute `public`. Here's a checklist when building for production with aot. ( Taken from this github project https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa, though it is applicable to any other angular project.)

AOT - Ahead of time compilation DON'TS

- Don’t use require statements for your templates or styles, use styleUrls and 
  templateUrls, the angular2-template-loader plugin will change it to require 
  at build time.
- Don’t use default exports.
- Don’t use form.controls.controlName, use form.get(‘controlName’)
- Don’t use control.errors?.someError, use control.hasError(‘someError’)
- Don’t use functions in your providers, routes or declarations, export a function and then reference that function name
  Inputs, Outputs, View or Content Child(ren), Hostbindings, and **any field you use from the template or annotate for Angular should be public**

**Keeping activatedRoute private**

To keep your activatedRoute private, you can do something like this

```
theData:any;
constructor (
private sessionService: SessionService,
private router: Router,
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
 ) {
     this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.theData= params['keyWorking']; 
        //you will bind the theData instead of the activatedROute
      }
    );
}
```

}

and in your template

```
<div class="confirmationMessage" *ngIf="theData == 'validateInscription'">
<br>Un lien de confirmation vous a été envoyé sur votre boîte email afin de 
 valider votre compte. Merci.</div>
```

Comment: But why is this behavior not consist? I mean why part of my private member in the view pass validation, while the other part throws an exception? What is the difference between them both???

Comment: it will pass if you are just running in development mode ( ng serve ) but it will not if you are going to build for production with aot enabled.

Comment: This isn't my question, why in `ng build` - part of my private members access-able in the html, while other throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

Please find more detail in [Property is private and only accessible within class](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5621)

Original "error" reported is not an error, but normal restriction of AOT at least for versions 2, 4, 5. The variable used in the template needs to be declared as "public". Template is treated as a separate Typescript class.

You can change all the components variable from private to public. If they are used into your template.

Or you can use ng build -prod --aot=false for building

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `activatedRoute` which you've injected into your `constructor` as a `private` variable. Meaning that you won't be able to access it from your template when using AOT.

Either change it to `public activatedRoute` or don't use it at all from the template to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try with " ng build -env=prod " command. It worked for me to solve this error.